# How to put php code inside opening and closing shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, echo, shortcode

I am working on a site and I am using a shortcode in my template files that has an opening and close. I would like to know if its possible to place wordpress the_content php tag in between the shortcode and if it's possible to the same thing with placing another shortcode in between opening and closing tags.

I've tried this -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[membership level="1"]''.$the_content.''[/membership]'); ?>
```

But it's not working, I tried a few others things as well. What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have tried using `get_the_content()` instead, if your worried about the stripped tags wrap in wpautop like so `wpautop(get_the_content())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you have extra single quotes?

try:

```
echo do_shortcode('[membership level="1"]'.$the_content.'[/membership]');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. However I tried your suggestion and nothing is showing

Comment: check that your code is actually outputting a string before you put it in the so_shortcode() function. According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode you are using correctly