# place PHP string inside do_shortcode opening and closing

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a membership based site where I need to restrict contact information. I need to insert this content inside opening and closing shortcode :

`[level-accountant][/level-accountant]`

The content I need to restrict is this :

```
<?php $order = array('billing_company', 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_state', 'country');
    $result = array();
    foreach($order as $elem){
    if($user_meta[$elem][0] != "")
    $result[] = $user_meta[$elem][0];
    }
    echo implode(', ', $result);
    ?>
```

I have followed this answer here :
[How to put php code inside opening and closing shortcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514401/how-to-put-php-code-inside-opening-and-closing-shortcodes)

and tried this code :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[level-accountant]'.$order = array('billing_company', 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_state', 'country');
    $result = array();
    foreach($order as $elem){
    if($user_meta[$elem][0] != "")
    $result[] = $user_meta[$elem][0];
    }
    echo implode(', ', $result);.'[/level-accountant]'); ?>
```

But just can't figure out how to place my content inside. This code is giving me errors.

Comment: I think you have some severe syntax error there...

Comment: I know that, but could you please point them out and correct the code ?

Comment: Matteo, the syntax that is displaying the contact information works great, I just can't figure out how to place it in between the shortcode ..

Comment: Why aren't you computing the result *before* doing the shortcode, and then just passing a single variable into it? It would be much easier to have something like `echo do_shortcode('[level-accountant]' . $result . '[/level-accountant]');`

Comment: @Mevius that sounds good. How should the complete code look like ?

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Answer (score 1):

This should be as easy as

```
$order = array('billing_company', 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_state', 'country');
$result = array();
foreach($order as $elem){
    if($user_meta[$elem][0] != "") {
        $result[] = $user_meta[$elem][0];
    }
}
echo do_shortcode('[level-accountant]'.implode(', ', $result).'[/level-accountant]');
```

In the above code, I just took the part of code which you wrongly put in the `do_shortcode()` call and placed it before, saving the result in a variable.

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer as you really helped. I can't due to my reputation score, because my questions are constantly getting downvoted by some idiots. As a result, my account will most probably be cancelled now by administrators.

Comment: I find the concept of this website quite idiotic to be quite honest. The reason why I ask questions is because I don't know the answers. It makes sense to me. If the question is stupid to some people, well I'm sorry I didn't know, but I really find it quite ridiculous that some idiots who don't know the answer can just downvote you for whatever reasons .. anyway, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am sorry but do not agree with you: the site rules could even seem "idiotic" as you say, but in the moment you subscribe, you should do your best to comprehend them and adhere to them... If you wish you can discuss those rules in the "meta" site :)

Comment: Appreciate your reply. See I asked 3 questions in total. All of them being downvoted seconds after published. Why ?? What is wrong with this question that i asked here for example ?  I don't see a reason why should somebody give it a downvote. I spent hours on searching for an answer, i'm not a php expert and need to have the answer rather visual to understand it. I am now restricted by the administrators to ask more questions. Pathetic isn't it ? If I could improve the question, so it's a "good question" by the rules, i probably would. But without a knowledge in this area, it's kind a tricky.

Comment: What did you change in their code to fix this problem? Code only answers are not useful to future visitors.